# When attempting to install Mojave on a 2014 Mac mini I get a blinking folder with question mark and can’t install the OS,

Tags: macos, ssd, formatting, recovery

Using 2014 Mac mini I bought and installed a brand new 500GB SSD Samsung 860 EVO, I did a recovery with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, I used Disk Utility to format the drive and then ran the Mojave installer.

After some loading, it gives me a black screen with a blinking folder and a question mark on it.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and possibly how to fix it?

Also, If I try “Mac OS Extended (Journaled)” formatting I get an error during installation that conversion to APFS fails.

Comment: When you formatted it, did you make sure it was GUID/HFS+ not MBR/HFS+ ?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, it is GUID